# What do books have over the SRD?

Tags: d20-system, books, ogl

I've recently learned that many d20 games have their rules accessible for free under OGL in form of a System Reference Document. I'd been quite reluctant to d20, but since it's free, I've thought of giving it a try.

My question is: what do official books add compared to the free SRD, apart from nice illustrations? I mean, settings, hooks? Extra rules?

Comment: This is too broad as applied to "every d20 game," as every game is different, but we have an extensive answer about that regarding Pathfinder which is representative.

Comment: Also note that it makes a **huge** difference whether you're joining an established group who are willing to help a new guy, versus learning on your own. I was fine with just the SRD -- and my friends. Without them, less sure.

Comment: I'd be happy to see this reopened if it was narrowed down to the specific d20-based game+SRD that Marshall is contemplating / has been avoiding.

Comment: @mxyzplk Thanks for the link. I'd looked for similar questions before asking but didn't find it.